# Suspected Corrupted Windows 7 MBR?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, mbr

So, this may not be the correct place to put up my question, but i'll give it a shot.

I'm having an issue repairing this computer. It was brought to me with the described issue of 'Not turning on'

Later, I found that it would come with the error of 'No boot sector found on internal hard drive.' I assumed it was an MBR issue due to a virus or cutting a Windows update short.

I booted into my trusty recovery enviroment and ran bootrec.exe /FIXMBR and restarted -- No luck

I started to think (After multiple attempts to get the MBR sorted out, including creating a new boot sector) that the Hard-drive was possibly starting to cave in on itself, so I booted into a linux bootable CD and went to check the SMART data. Odd, say's it's inaccessible.

That seems odd to me, considering it's a newer (two years old or so) Windows 7 computer. All new Hard-drives have SMART. So, I checked the BIOS. No mention of SMART anywhere. Greaaaat.

I decided as a last-ditch effort to switch the hard-drive type to ATA in the BIOS (God knows why, I was getting frusterated) instead of AHCI. VOILA! It actually attempts to boot, gets halfway through the little windows animation, does an incredibly (Half a second) quick BSOD, and shuts down.

Does anyone have ideas on what's going on here? I'm at my wits end.

Comment: switching off ahci will cause bsod if the OS was installed with it On, switch it back. Try doing a hard reset of the bios by pulling the cmos battery for 15 minutes. after this is done enter the bios and set date and time and be sure ahci is enabled, then try to boot.

Comment: If that does not get it booting try the command here...http://www.ehow.com/how_4836283_repair-mbr-windows.html

Comment: When you say that Linux said “it’s inaccessible”, what do you mean by “it”. Are you referring to the SMART data or the drive itself? Did the drive *used* to work in that system? Ask whomever brought it to you what they did or changed just before it stopped working. Maybe it’s a virus *what done it*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot even see the drive in the BIOS, it sounds like a hardware (configuration?) problem as opposed to a boot-record/sector issue. Check that the cable has not come loose; that is a common and easy to fix cause of this type of problem (especially for SATA cables).

Comment: As some more clarification: It's a laptop, the BIOS DOES detect the primary drive to be 500GB's

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on what to do here?

Comment: @AridDecay - It sounds like the operating system is toast.  Some problems just can't be fixed.  I suggest you duplicate the drive and then try to extract the data.

Comment: I meant that since the BIOS cannot see it *correctly*. If the BIOS is incapable of accessing the drive anymore, then either the drive is damaged or the connection is bad. It may be a laptop, but they are not immune. Just yesterday I read a comment by a high-rep user here explaining how sufficient jostling can cause laptop drives to eventually come loose from their connectors.